# String to array of JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

I try to send data to my NodeJS server using HTTP protocol (vue-resource). I want to send a array of JSON object like this :  `[{"name":"Charlotte","surname":"Chacha","birth":"2000-04-02"},{"name":"Michael","surname":"Mic","birth":"1999-01-30"}]`.

My front code :

```
window.onload = function () {
  var gamme = new Vue({
    el:'#gamme',
    data: {
      myListe: []      
    },
    methods: {
      sendListe: function() {
        this.$http.get("/NewListe?liste="+this.myListe).then(response=> {
          if (response.body) {
            console.log(response.body);
          }
        });           
      }
    }
    })
}
```

And my back code :

```
server.app.get("/NewListe", function(req, res) {
  try {
    let liste= req.query.liste;
    console.log(liste);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```

When I try to display the variable `liste` in the server side console, I obtain this : `[object Object]` . `liste` is a string type that I can't use. I would like to have an array of JSON, like in front.

I tried to parse like this `JSON.parse(operationsGamme)` , but I have this error : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: did you tried `"/NewListe?liste="+JSON.stringify(this.myListe)`?

Comment: The problem is that `"/NewListe?liste="+this.myListe` results in `"/NewListe?liste=[object%20Object]"`. You can use stringify but a better solution is to use a POST request instead. Note that there's no such thing as a "JSON object". `this.myListe` is an object, and sending it to the server is done by turning it into a JSON string i.e. text.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Yes I tried. I still have a string variable, when I tried to log it, I have this : ```[,]```. And if I want to parse it, I have the same error than before.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried by changing GET into POST on both side, and the problem still persist.

Comment: You're probably still sending it as part of the URL then. Use `this.$http.post("/NewListe", { liste: this.myListe })` instead, make sure express has bodyparser middleware enabled, then use server.app.post(...) and check `req.body.liste`

Comment: @ChrisG ok, it works better now ! Tank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should surely be using a POST method if you are sending JSON data to the server - a GET just isn't designed for that sort of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have passed a JSON in the url, it will be URLEncoded. So, in the backend before you do `JSON.parse(liste)`, you should do `decodeURI(liste)`. `decodeURI()` will return the JSON string which you can parse and use it in your code. I hope this will fix your problem.